# Enviar formulario a un correo con ajax y php

Tags: php, jquery, html5, ajax

tengo un problema y es que quiero enviar un formulario a un correo con ajax, y al enviarlo no llega ningún dato al correo, es para evitar que la pagina recargue.
necesito ayuda ya que la pagina no envía ningún formulario al correo no se que estaré haciendo mal, espero y me pueden ayuda con una solución simple.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendEmail(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/send.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            success: function(res){
                alert('Succes!');
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<?php
$name = $_POST['Fname'];
$Sname = $_POST['Sname'];
$case = $_POST['case'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$userDestiny = "shocknoisepromo@gmail.com";

$header = "From: $name $Sname" . "\r\n";
$header .= "Email: $email" . "\r\n";
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

mail($userDestiny,$case,$message,$header);
```

?>

Comment: El código PHP de envío de email debe estar en este archivo: `php/send.php` y debes verificar que los datos se están enviando bien. En Ajax puedes hacer un `console.log( $('#form').serialize() );` y en PHP puedes hacer un `var_dump($_POST);` para ver si los datos se están enviando o no.

Comment: esta en el archivo amigo

Comment: ¿Hiciste las dos pruebas que te dije, tanto en el servidor como en el cliente? Que quede claro que la parte de Ajax debe estar en **un archivo distinto a `php/send.php`** ¿Es así?

Answer (score 0):

Serialize

```
$('#form').serialize()
```

Te arrojara un string que lo interpreta el metodo GET

Sustituye data por

```
data: {
    campo: valor,
    campo2: valor2,
},
```